# jQuery sweetalert2 function does not

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

This worked just fine with the original sweetalert, but with sweetalert2 it never runs the function to reload my ajax data.

Can anyone see an error?

```
         .on('click', '#saveRider', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/saveRiderClass.php',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#addRidersForm').serialize(),
                success: function (json) {
                    if (json && json.status && json.already_entered === false) {
                        swal({
                                title: "Rider Saved and Classes Added!",
                                type: "success"
                            },
                            function (isConfirm) {
                                if (isConfirm === true) {
                                    $("#enteredRiders").load("ajax/getEnteredRiders.php");
                                    $("#uniqueRiders").load("ajax/getUniqueRiders.php");
                                    $("#totalRiders").load("ajax/getTotalEntries.php");
                                }
                            });
                    }
                    else if (json && json.status && json.already_entered === true) {
                        swal({
                            title: "Rider already entered in that class",
                            type: "warning"
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the migration guide from sweetalert to sweetalert2. Sweetalert2 does not use callbacks anymore but promises instead.

You can find all the migration details [here](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2)

EDIT: Here's how you should modify your code. I'm taking the first sweetalert call you do.

This call:

```
swal({
        title: "Rider Saved and Classes Added!",
        type: "success"
      },
      function (isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm === true) {
              $("#enteredRiders").load("ajax/getEnteredRiders.php");
              $("#uniqueRiders").load("ajax/getUniqueRiders.php");
              $("#totalRiders").load("ajax/getTotalEntries.php");
          }
      });
```

should become something like that:

```
swal({
        title: "Rider Saved and Classes Added!",
        type: "success"
      }.then(function () {
          $("#enteredRiders").load("ajax/getEnteredRiders.php");
          $("#uniqueRiders").load("ajax/getUniqueRiders.php");
          $("#totalRiders").load("ajax/getTotalEntries.php");
      });
```

Notice the `.then` before the `function()`

Using `.then` you are using promises just as sweetaler2 expects instead of callbacks.

Comment: I added an example from your code. It should help you see the difference.

Comment: Ahh.. I did read the migration guide, but didn't really see a huge difference. I'll try this.

Comment: It's the formatting on the guide that threw me off.. I didn't see the .then on there.. :)

Comment: nice answer @ChandlerBing42! I made the little amend according to changes in [v4.0.0](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v4.0.0) of swal2

Comment: Thanks @limonte ! I didn't see these changes :)